# monads-tf: MonadReader instance for MonadState

Tags: haskell, monads, typeclass, monad-transformers, type-families

Consider the next example. I have a monad `MyM` that is just a `StateT`

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Reader

type MyS = Int
type MyM = StateT MyS
```

Usually `MyM` is used for reading and writing `MyS` state, so I have functions like the next:

```
f1 :: (MonadState m, StateType m ~ MyS) => m ()
f1 = modify (+1)
```

But sometimes I need just to read `MyS`, so I want `MonadReader` context instead of `MonadState`:

```
f2 :: (MonadReader m, EnvType m ~ MyS) => m Int
f2 = liftM (+1) ask
```

And I want to write something like:

```
f3 :: (MonadState m, StateType m ~ MyS) => m Int
f3 = f1 >> f2
```

So basically I need every `MonadState` instance to be `MonadReader` instance too with the correspondent family type. Something like

```
instance MonadState m => MonadReader where
  type EnvType m = StateType m
  ...
```

But I can't find the way how to make it type check. Is it possible to express such the relation between `MonadState` and `MonadReader`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is essentially `ask` to have the same effect as `get`. I can't help but wonder why you don't just use `get` in that case :)

If your aim is to write code that either reads the state or the env depending on what is available, you have to ask what you plan to do with, say, `ReaderT r (StateT s m) a`, where you have both. For that reason, you can't just do:

```
instance MonadState m => MonadReader m where
  type EnvType m = StateType m
  ask = get
```

because you'll conflict with existing instances. You can, however, do:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, TypeFamilies #-}
newtype ReadState m a = RS { unRS :: m a }
  deriving (Monad)

instance MonadState m => MonadReader (ReadState m) where
  type EnvType (ReadState m) = StateType m
  ask = RS get
  local f (RS m) = RS $ do
    s <- get
    modify f
    x <- m
    put s
    return x
```

Then if you have a polymorphic reader value like `f2`, you can pull a `MonadState` out of it with `unRS`. If you want to use some more devious extensions, try this with `RankNTypes`:

```
useStateAsEnv :: (MonadState n) => (forall m . (MonadReader m, EnvType m ~ StateType n) => m a) -> n a
useStateAsEnv m = unRS m
```

Then you can do `useStateAsEnv (liftM (+1) ask)` and get a `MonadState` value. I haven't thoroughly investigated how useful this is in practice, however – to produce a value of type `forall m. MonadReader m => m a`, you can pretty much only use `ask`, `local`, and monadic functions.

Here's a similar, less general but probably more useful thing, using standard transformers:

```
readerToState :: (Monad m) => ReaderT r m a -> StateT r m a
readerToState reader = StateT $ \env -> do
  res <- runReaderT reader env
  return (res, env)
```

---

Edit: thinking about this later you could probably generalise this to any state monad transformer with `lift . runReaderT reader =<< get`, but the type starts to be rather unwieldy:

```
:: (Monad m, MonadTrans t, MonadState (t m)) => ReaderT (StateType (t m)) m b -> t m b
```

which *is* a generalisation of the above but may not actually be a useful one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't want to use `get` since I want to force `f2` not to modify state. Using `get` will not allow compiler to say me that `put` is used somewhere in `f2`

Comment: Hmm. On second thoughts, the `ReadState` newtype may not actually be all that useful. If you're sticking to standard transformers, the `readerToState` that I just edited in is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Great! `readerToState` is ok for me. I'm going to accept the answer. Thanks.